# In python type-hinting, how can I make an argument accept any subclass of a base class?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function that looks a bit like this. I want the function to accept any subclass of io.IOBase - in other words, any file-like object.

```
def import_csv_file(f:io.IOBase)->pandas.DataFrame:
    return pandas.read_csv(f)
```

When I view the object in IntelliJ, the JetBrains implementation of type-hinting rejects any input unless I provide exactly an instance of io.IOBase - but what if I want to pass in an instance of a sub-class of io.IOBase? Is there a way to change the type-hint to say that this is allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you annotate a function argument with the base class (`io.IOBase` in your case) then you can also pass instances of any subtype of the base class – inheritance applies to annotation types as well.

That said, you could use [`typing.IO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.io) as a generic type representing any I/O stream (and `typing.TextIO` and `typing.BinaryIO` for binary and text I/O streams respectively).

Comment: What would be a more general solution for this? If you had an `Animal` and a `BigAnimal` and wanted to write an API that accepted any object that was a subclass of `Animal`, how would you do that?