# Python typing not accepting subclasses

Tags: python, python-typing

I have 3 classes:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Parent:
    field_a: int

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Child(Parent):
    field_b: int

class Wrapper(NamedTuple):
    object_a: Dict[int, Parent]
    object_b: Dict[int, Parent]
```

According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279799/in-python-type-hinting-how-can-i-make-an-argument-accept-any-subclass-of-a-base), it looks like I should be able to replace instances of Parent with Child in Wrapper. However, when I'm writing a function like this:

```
def get_wrapper()->Wrapper:
    return Wrapper(object_a={1: Child(1,2)}, object_b={2: Child(2,3)})
```

pyre gives me something like "Expected `Dict[int, Parent]` for 1st parameter `object_a` to call `Wrapper.__init__` but got `Dict[int, Child]`."

Could anyone explain why using a subclass doesn't work in this case, and how I can get around this?

EDIT:
I seem to have oversimplified the problem in the example I gave. My get_wrapper function was actually doing something like this:

```
def get_child()->Child:
    return Child(1,2)
def get_wrapper()->Wrapper:
    child_a = get_child()
    child_b = get_child()
    return Wrapper(object_a={1: child_a}, object_b={2: child_b})
```

I fixed the type errors by changing the return type of get_child to be Parent.

Comment: `mypy` finds no issues in this

Comment: [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *complete*, minimal and representative. The provided sample code is incomplete due to missing import statements.

Comment: I can't reproduce with `pyre`, either.

Comment: Latest version of pycharm also doesn't seen any issues with your example.   What version of pyre are you using?

Comment: Sorry, my question was incomplete. Updated my question to give a fuller picture. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

While your question seems fragmented across multiple edits, this is what I ran against **mypy** 0.920 and **pyre** 0.9.8. None of the type checkers raised any error.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, NamedTuple


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Parent:
    field_a: int


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Child(Parent):
    field_b: int


class Wrapper(NamedTuple):
    object_a: Dict[int, Parent]
    object_b: Dict[int, Parent]


def get_child() -> Child:
    return Child(1, 2)


def get_wrapper() -> Wrapper:
    child_a = get_child()
    child_b = get_child()
    return Wrapper(object_a={1: child_a}, object_b={2: child_b})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_wrapper()
```